# performing ajax validation in onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await, onsubmit

I'm trying to perform some AJAX validation in a submit() handler for a web form. The ajax is being performed with `$.ajax()` from jquery. If I use `async: false` it works great but I get a deprecation notice and I'd just assume have code that's future proof.

So my question is how can I perform AJAX validation without `async: false`?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865124/569976 recommends the `when()` function. idk how I can use that for my purposes. I suppose I could have that set a global variable `complete` to `true` in the `done()` part of the `when()` method but how do I know when `complete` is set to true? I suppose I could do `setInterval` to keep on checking the value of `complete` until it's finally true and could then use JS to submit the form but idk that seems inelegant.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038050/569976 mentions `$.ajaxStop` but I gather that's not best practices.

I also tried this (in the `$('...').submit(...)` method):

```
await Promise.all(function() {
    return $.ajax(...);
})
```

That got me a `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should perform your input sanitization and validations before you submit via Ajax. So you could do it before you construct the Ajax request or in a beforeSend event... Preferably as early as possible so you could avoid canceled/aborted constructed Ajax requests.

As for your syntax error, I would check out the documentation on Promise.all as to the type it returns.